# Python 3.3.2 - Finding Image Sources in HTML

Tags: html, regex, python-3.x

I need to locate and extract image sources from an html file. For example, it might contain:

```
<image class="logo" src="http://example.site/logo.jpg">
```

or

```
<img src="http://another.example/picture.png">
```

Using Python. I would not like to use any third party programs. I can use the RE module, though. The program should:

- sift through everything
- seek out the `img` or `image` tags
- find the `src` and get the attribute value (without the double quotes)

Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it? We can assume that I don't need to access the internet to do this (I have a file called website.html that contains all the html code).

EDIT: My current Regex expression is

`r'<img[^>]*\ssrc="(.*?)"'`

and

`r'<image[^>]*\ssrc="(.*?)"'`.

The main problem is that the expression will pick up anything starting with img or image. For example, if there was something saying `<imagesomethingrandom src="website">`, it would still count that as an image (as the word image is at the start) and it would add the source.

Thanks in advance.

Rob.

Comment: Take a look at [RegularExpressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and try to learn regular expressions.  When you have a decent understanding of them, and have tried to write the expression your self, come back and edit the question.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I have already learned the different syntax for Regex. I _can_ find the tags (<img>), but I do not know how to put the inside of the tags inside a list. That is why I am asking the question.

Comment: Okay, then please share your expression.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Done and done.

Comment: What was your outcome?

Comment: @hwnd The expression would work, but it would apply to everything that started with <img or <image. This meant that something like <imagesomething would be included, and I don't want that to happen. I want it to strictly look for <img and <image.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This expression will:

- find all `image` and `img` tags which have a `src` attribute
- ignore tags which are not image or img, like `imagesomethingrandom`
- capture the value of the src attribute
- correctly handle single, double or non quoted attribute values
- avoid most of the tricky edge cases which seem to trip up regular expresses when matching html

`<ima?ge?(?=\s|>)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=(['"]?)(.*?)\1(?:\s|>))(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>`

[image]

## Examples

[Live Regex Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/i1O6g76B27)
[Live Python Demo](http://repl.it/J0t/6)

**Sample Text**

Note the rather difficult edge cases in the first line

```
<img onmouseover=' src="NotTheDroidsYouAreLookingFor.png" ; if (x > 3) { funRotate(src); } ' src="http://another.example/picture.png">
<imagesomethingrandom class="logo" src="http://example.site/imagesomethingrandom.jpg">
<image class="logo" src="http://example.site/logo.jpg">
<img src="http://another.example/DoubleQuoted.png">
<image src='http://another.example/SingleQuoted.png'>
<img src=http://another.example/NotQuoted.png>
```

**Python Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

string = """<img onmouseover=' src="NotTheDroidsYouAreLookingFor.png" ; if (x > 3) { funRotate(src); } ' src="http://another.example/picture.png">
<imagesomethingrandom class="logo" src="http://example.site/imagesomethingrandom.jpg">
<image class="logo" src="http://example.site/logo.jpg">
<img src="http://another.example/DoubleQuoted.png">
<image src='http://another.example/SingleQuoted.png'>
<img src=http://another.example/NotQuoted.png>
""";

regex = r"""<ima?ge?(?=\s|>)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=(['"]?)(.*?)\1(?:\s|>))(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>""";

intCount = 0

for matchObj in re.finditer( regex, string, re.M|re.I|re.S):
    print " "
    print "[", intCount, "][ 0 ] : ", matchObj.group(0)
    print "[", intCount, "][ 1 ] : ", matchObj.group(1)
    print "[", intCount, "][ 2 ] : ", matchObj.group(2)
    intCount+=1
```

**Capture Groups**

Group 0 gets the entire image or img tag
Group 1 gets the quote which surrounded src attribute, if it exists
Group 2 gets the src attribute value

```
[ 0 ][ 0 ] :  <img onmouseover=' src="NotTheDroidsYouAreLookingFor.png" ; if (x > 3) { funRotate(src); } ' src="http://another.example/picture.png">
[ 0 ][ 1 ] :  "
[ 0 ][ 2 ] :  http://another.example/picture.png

[ 1 ][ 0 ] :  <image class="logo" src="http://example.site/logo.jpg">
[ 1 ][ 1 ] :  "
[ 1 ][ 2 ] :  http://example.site/logo.jpg

[ 2 ][ 0 ] :  <img src="http://another.example/DoubleQuoted.png">
[ 2 ][ 1 ] :  "
[ 2 ][ 2 ] :  http://another.example/DoubleQuoted.png

[ 3 ][ 0 ] :  <image src='http://another.example/SingleQuoted.png'>
[ 3 ][ 1 ] :  '
[ 3 ][ 2 ] :  http://another.example/SingleQuoted.png

[ 4 ][ 0 ] :  <img src=http://another.example/NotQuoted.png>
[ 4 ][ 1 ] :  
[ 4 ][ 2 ] :  http://another.example/NotQuoted.png
```

Comment: how did you generate the regex graph ? it's impressive

Comment: the regex does not allow additionnal space before and after equal sign. Example <img src = "https://myhost.com/img/good.png">

Comment: Very true this edge case and many others might exist. This edge case can be accommodated by adding `\ *` [that's a backslash space asterisk] before and after the equal signs. But HTML best practices recommend not including spaces around the equal signs for readability and more importantly this edge case wasn't covered by the OP's sample text.

Answer (score 0):

And an altered version

```
<ima?ge? # using conditional letters, we match both tags in one expression
\s+      # require at least one space, also includes newlines which are valid
         # prevents <imgbutnotreally> tags
[^>]*?   # similar to the above, but tell it not to be greedy (performance)
\bsrc="([^"]+) # match a space and find all characters in the src tag
```

#### [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/qOv7UVSDM7)

```
<ima?ge?\s+[^>]*?\src="([^"]+)
```

Comment: A slightly better way is: <ima?ge?\s+[^>]*?src=["|']([^["|']]+) as it also caters for single quotes around the name.

Comment: You're using character classes incorrectly in the last regex.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't notice that.  I guess `<img src=|thing.png|>` shouldn't be accepted.

Comment: This portion of your expression `([^["']]+)` doesn't quite do what you think it does, you might consider rewriting this part.

Comment: Thanks.  I just rolled it back to the second revision and made one minor, tested, change.  I updated the rubular too.

Answer (score 0):

Try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), just write

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
soup = BeautifulSoup(theHTMLtext)
imagesElements = soup.find_all('img')
```

Answer (score 0):

To find some image in a html using soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = <img src="http://another.example/picture.png">

a = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
b = a.findAll('img')
url_picture = list()
for i in range(0, len(b)):
    image = b[i].attrs['src']
    url_picture.append(image)
```